# XCode Analyzer potential memory leak on CGContextClip

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, static, analysis

The xcode Analyzer is saying there is a potential memory leak stored onto 'path' when using CGContextClip.  What would be causing this potential memory leak?

```
- (UIImage *)imageMaskToEllipseWithBorderWidth:(float)boarderWidth andBorderColor:(UIColor *)borderColor
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextRetinaAware( self.size );
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height), NULL);
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextClip(context);   // *** Warning is shown here during static analysis ***

    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height)];

    if( boarderWidth > 0  &&  borderColor != nil )
    {
        [borderColor set];
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
        CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height));
    }

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

[image]

Comment: you can click at the blue icon on the right hand side before "Potential...". Xcode will show you how can it leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029):

> Core Foundation functions have names that indicate when you own a
>   returned object:
>
> - Object-creation functions that have “Create” embedded in the name;
> - Object-duplication functions that have “Copy” embedded in the name.
>
> If you own an object, it is your responsibility to relinquish
>   ownership (using `CFRelease`) when you have finished with it.

[and also Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW1) :

> **The compiler does not automatically manage the lifetimes of Core Foundation objects**; you must call `CFRetain` and `CFRelease` (or the corresponding type-specific variants) as dictated by the Core Foundation memory management rules.

You created `path` here,

```
CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height), NULL);
```

but you didn't release it. The `path` was leaked. So, you got the warning.

---

To fix that, just add the below code after you finish using `path`,

```
CFRelease(path);
```

Comment: Since I am using Arc wouldn't it do the release for me?

Comment: Thank you so much for answer.  Good thing I ran the analyzer.